# Angular 1.x component templateUrl not rendering in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my component setup like so:

```
// app/my-component/my-component.js
app.component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
        bindingA: '=',
        bindingB: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/my-component/my-component.tpl.html',
    controller: MyComponentCtrl
});

// app/my-component/my-component.tpl.html
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.bindingA" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.bindingB" />
</div>
```

No errors are thrown; my template file shows up just fine in Chrome's Dev Tools. Network preview of the XHR request shows up right but it just won't render on the DOM...

If I swap out `templateUrl` with `template`, the string will display just fine in the DOM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your console throw error, like 404's?

Comment: @Mikey None. Comes in as 200 and I can even preview the template in dev tools. Just won't show up on the DOM even with an inspect. One thing that I'm not sure will have an effect on it but the parent element of the component is hidden on page load and then is display after a few user events.

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya What? That is exactly the problem in the other question, don't do that!

Comment: @Mikey, yup, my apologies, I flipped it in my brain.

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya No problem. We all make mistakes :)

Comment: @ChuckieSullivan That sounds very much like your problem. Can you strip it out of the parent element and see if that works?

Comment: @Mikey Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: Ended up just in-lining it in the JavaScript. Hoping to find a solution soon and posting an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

After wanting to beat my head on the keyboard, I realized that this bit of code was interfering will the templateUrl responses:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
            'response': function (response) {
                response.data = response.data.d;

                return response;
            }
        }
    });
```

Simply changed to: `if (response.data.d) response.data = response.data.d;`

Another day in the life I'll tell ya...